# sendrawtransaction and txn-mempool-conflict

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

When i sendrawtransaction to bitcoind, i get error (exceptions) `18: txn-mempool-conflict` (use Bitcoin JSON-RPC [denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc](https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc))
But the transaction is sent to the network and is subsequently confirmed.

Example one decoded transaction : https://jsfiddle.net/rn58a4j6/

then i send this transaction:
94ec12fc463230b4285a29b047608627c05572a4c6eabe6688a201ce49ae72f7

Comment: looks like you already submitted the transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I restarted bitcoind.

I think that maybe when i was developing my project, I made a bad transaction and it saved in mempool